# is this possible to debug and edit a live python code on server. if yes then how can we do it?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, server

Following are the details

server name = digital ocean
language = python
please let me know what's the appropriate way for debugging the code?
thanks in advance
favor will be appreciated

Comment: In general, this is a "never do this unless production is already down, and even then it's bad practice".  Reproduce the issue in your development environment, write appropriate tests to prove it's fixed, and then deploy it normally.

Comment: but the issue is that i cannot configure it locally as its on docker and i am not much familiar with docker.
 live the code is working i just need to change small functionalities so i decided to debug it live.